# Exposing Android app services over Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

Is it possible to expose some kind of custom app services/profile over Bluetooth?
For example, if I have an app that provides some functionality like

```
fun doSomething(params) 
fun doSomethingElse(params)
```

would it be possible to expose this functionality over Bluetooth to a connected device in a similar fashion as REST API exposes methods to clients?

In other words, I'd like to build Android (Bluetooth) "server" app that surrounding devices can connect to and make some actions on it over Bluetooth.

Can you point me to any tutorial where I can look into it?